# Separator between "in:" and maintitle

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I meet some problems of bibliographical style because of my modifications.
I modified my style to correspond at norms of my director but modifications are note very "clean".
Sometimes, books have no authors or a editor  but with my modification I have a dash but I don’t want this just for this case.

At the beginning, I had modified with this line  to have like in example : `\setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock`

In : byeditor dir. – booktitle

But I would want to have only in case books have neither authors nor a editor:

In : booktitle …

I do not know if I was very understandable because my English is very bad.

Thanks !

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{csquotes} 

%MACRO

\providecommand{\ier}{\textsuperscript{er}}
\providecommand{\iers}{\textsuperscript{ers}}
\providecommand{\iere}{\textsuperscript{ère}}
\providecommand{\ieres}{\textsuperscript{ères}}
\providecommand{\ieme}{\textsuperscript{e}}
\providecommand{\iemes}{\textsuperscript{es}}
\providecommand{\nd}{\textsuperscript{nd}}
\providecommand{\nds}{\textsuperscript{nds}}
\providecommand{\nde}{\textsuperscript{nde}}
\providecommand{\ndes}{\textsuperscript{ndes}}
\providecommand{\no}{\textsuperscript{o}}
\providecommand{\nos}{\textsuperscript{os}}
\providecommand{\mme}{M\textsuperscript{me}\space}
\providecommand{\mmes}{M\textsuperscript{mes}\space}
\providecommand{\mr}{M.\space}
\providecommand{\mrs}{MM.\space}

  \usepackage[              %                                                                                   
  backend=bibtex,%
  style=authoryear, %
autolang=hyphen,%
 firstinits, mergedate=false, style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999                          % Configuration de la bilio
]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\parentext{#1}}                   %parenthèse de l'initiale
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}                %tiret après le label
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                          rajoute date

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1} 
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace\addcolon\space}}

  %Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
          \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
              \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
             }%
         }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}


%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extraalpha}}
\makeatother



% "Et al." en ITALIQUE

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

 %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother

    %minuscule citation
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}} 

%Enlève parenthèse colloque

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{                        
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
      \bibstring{presentedat}%
      \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext{%
       \printfield{venue}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}


    \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
 byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%                         
 {Établit\space par}%
{dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
in = {\textit{in}},%                                    %et en italique
 editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
 editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
 opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
idem = {\emph{idem}},%
byeditor = {dir\adddot},% Remplace sous la direction de pour les improceedings etc. 
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
%pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
 %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}

%modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%


%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother


% put (dir.) at the end (byeditor)  pour tout ce qui est in : auteur dir.
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
    % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
%     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%% 
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%% 
     \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%% 
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
 \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins 
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
%  \newunit\newblock %%%% enlever
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \ifnameundef{namea}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printtext{}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\space}%
     \printfield{number}%
     \printtext{}}%
     }} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

     %Rajoute une virgule après le titre du journal et avant le numéro du volume     
     \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Inproceedings{bats1994,
  Title                    = {La vaisselle culinaire comme marqueur culturel: l'exemple de la Gaule méridionale et de la Grande Grèce (IV\ieme{}-I\ier{} s. av. J.-C.)},
  Author                   = {Michel Bats},
  Booktitle                = {Terre cuite et société. La céramique, document technique, économique, culturel},
  Pages                    = {407-424},
  Year                     = {1994},
  Address                  = {Juan-Les-Pins},
  Publisher                = {APDCA},
  Eventdate                = {1993-10-21/1993-10-23},
  Venue                    = {Actes des XIVe rencontres internationales d'Archéologie et d'Histoire d'Antibes}
}

@Inproceedings{bats1989,
  Title                    = {La Provence protohistorique},
  Author                   = {Michel Bats},
  Booktitle                = {La Provence des origines à l'an mil},
  Pages                    = {169-256},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Address                  = {Paris},
  Editor                   = {Paul-Albert Février and Michel Bats and Gabriel Camps and Michel Fixot and Jean Guyon and Jean Riser},
  Publisher                = {Ouest-France},
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document} 

\cite{bats1994, bats1989}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

**Edit :** For information this is my reel preamble if you have time to improve that or some advise.

```
\usepackage[                %                                                                                   
  backend=bibtex,%
  style=authoryear, %
% autolang=other*, %permet de repéré la langue avec langid =
autolang=hyphen,%
 firstinits, mergedate=false, style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999                          % Configuration de la bilio
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibliographie/bibliography}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.1\itemsep} %% permet d'augmenter de 10% l'espace entre les entrées biblio

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\parentext{#1}}                   %parenthèse de l'initiale
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}                %tiret après le label
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                          rajoute date

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1} 
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace\addcolon\space}}

  %Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
          \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
              \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
             }%
         }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}


%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extraalpha}}
\makeatother



% "Et al." en ITALIQUE

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

 %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother

    %minuscule citation
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}} 

%Enlève parenthèse colloque

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{                        
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
      \bibstring{presentedat}%
      \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext{%
       \printfield{venue}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}


    \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
 byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%                         
 {Établit\space par}%
{dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
in = {\textit{in}},%                                    %et en italique
 editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
 editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
 opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
idem = {\emph{idem}},%
byeditor = {dir\adddot},% Remplace sous la direction de pour les improceedings etc. 
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
%pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
 %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}

%modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%


%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother


% put (dir.) at the end (byeditor)  pour tout ce qui est in : auteur dir.
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
    % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
%     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%% 
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%% 
     \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%% 
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

%inverse non prénom pour in : quelquechoses




 %%modifié book pour virgule
 \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%     rajoute a la fin series + nomber pour avoir la collection a la fin de la ligne. La modification du style est plus bas.
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  %Change ordre des entrées pour les in quelquechoses : 
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
 \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins 
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
%  \newunit\newblock %%%% enlever
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{proceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}% rajoute collection
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \ifnameundef{namea}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{% modifier pour la thèse la virgule après la date
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}% remplacer par la version du book
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma %rajouter addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printtext{}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\space}%
     \printfield{number}%
     \printtext{}}%
     }} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

     %Rajoute une virgule après le titre du journal et avant le numéro du volume     
     \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
```

Comment: Please note that your code could be streamlined a bit, you for example have to re-definitions of `begentry` of which only the last one survives. Maybe I can find the time to comment on it later if you are interested.

Comment: I suspected it, but I do not too much know how to make. And given that until now it met my needs I had not asked more question.
But if you have time, it is with pleasure!
Indeed, I remove others parts of my code wich concerns books, thesis etc, with ugly modification ˆˆ

Comment: I have had a look, and only the double `begentry` is confusing. The rest looks OK, some things could be streamlined, but that is not something I can do without knowing exactly what the outcome ought to be. If have made some modifications (most for easier legibility for me), they are included in the MWE below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
\ifentrytype{article}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibstring{in}}%
   \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}
```

Where we make sure that the `\intitlepunct` goes into the punctuation buffer and is not overriden by any following punctuation.

MWE (with a few modifications)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%MACRO

\providecommand{\ier}{\textsuperscript{er}}
\providecommand{\iers}{\textsuperscript{ers}}
\providecommand{\iere}{\textsuperscript{ère}}
\providecommand{\ieres}{\textsuperscript{ères}}
\providecommand{\ieme}{\textsuperscript{e}}
\providecommand{\iemes}{\textsuperscript{es}}
\providecommand{\nd}{\textsuperscript{nd}}
\providecommand{\nds}{\textsuperscript{nds}}
\providecommand{\nde}{\textsuperscript{nde}}
\providecommand{\ndes}{\textsuperscript{ndes}}
\providecommand{\no}{\textsuperscript{o}}
\providecommand{\nos}{\textsuperscript{os}}
\providecommand{\mme}{M\textsuperscript{me}\space}
\providecommand{\mmes}{M\textsuperscript{mes}\space}
\providecommand{\mr}{M.\space}
\providecommand{\mrs}{MM.\space}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,%
  style=authoryear, %
  autolang=hyphen,%
  dashed=false,
  firstinits, mergedate=false, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\parentext{#1}}  
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space} 
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%          

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
       {}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]
          {\printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
           \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
           \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}}


\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

 %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother


\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}

%Enlève parenthèse colloque

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {\bibstring{presentedat}%
     \printfield{eventtitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{venue}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printeventdate
  \newunit}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
   byeditor = {\iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}
                 {Établit\space par}%
                 {dir\adddotspace\smartof}},
in = {\textit{in}},%                                    %et en italique
 editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
 editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
 opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
idem = {\emph{idem}},%
byeditor = {dir\adddot},% Remplace sous la direction de pour les improceedings etc.
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
%pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
 %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}

%modifie les pages des articles ... par pp. au lieu de p.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%


%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother


% put (dir.) at the end (byeditor)  pour tout ce qui est in : auteur dir.
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
    % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
%     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%%
     \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit*{\textendash\space}\newblock            %%%remplace \newunit\newblock pour rajouter un tiret entre le dir. et le mainttille des bouquins
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
%  \newunit\newblock %%%% enlever
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \ifnameundef{namea}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
     \printtext{}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit*{\space}%
     \printfield{number}%
     \printtext{}}%
     }} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

     %Rajoute une virgule après le titre du journal et avant le numéro du volume
     \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Inproceedings{bats1994,
  Title                    = {La vaisselle culinaire comme marqueur culturel: l'exemple de la Gaule méridionale et de la Grande Grèce (IV\ieme{}-I\ier{} s. av. J.-C.)},
  Author                   = {Michel Bats},
  Booktitle                = {Terre cuite et société. La céramique, document technique, économique, culturel},
  Pages                    = {407-424},
  Year                     = {1994},
  Address                  = {Juan-Les-Pins},
  Publisher                = {APDCA},
  Eventdate                = {1993-10-21/1993-10-23},
  Venue                    = {Actes des XIVe rencontres internationales d'Archéologie et d'Histoire d'Antibes}
}

@Inproceedings{bats1989,
  Title                    = {La Provence protohistorique},
  Author                   = {Michel Bats},
  Booktitle                = {La Provence des origines à l'an mil},
  Pages                    = {169-256},
  Year                     = {1989},
  Address                  = {Paris},
  Editor                   = {Paul-Albert Février and Michel Bats and Gabriel Camps and Michel Fixot and Jean Guyon and Jean Riser},
  Publisher                = {Ouest-France},
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{bats1994, bats1989, knuth:ct:a, knuth:ct:b, knuth:ct:c,
sigfridsson, worman, geer, cicero, wilde, salam, moraux}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: part of example output]

Comment: It's already in my preambule :

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1} 
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                 enlève guillemets articles
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

Comment: @Axelito Nope it isn't. Look closely what happens to `\intitlepunct`.

Comment: Oops! I am really stupid!
Thank you are really good in latex it's very impressive